# Retrieve data from parse using objective c

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve data from parse server and store in an array. I don't know what I have done wrong here. Can anyone help me out for my situation. Also, is it possible that I can use query to define condition. I want to register for user. Then when I login, the user's data is loaded from parse.

```
-(void)retrieveDataFromParse
{
    //retrive userdata and show in main menu
    NSString * username = _txtLoginUserName.text;
    NSString * password = _txtLoginPassword.text;
    PFQuery * query =[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
    [query whereKey:@"EmailID" equalTo:username];
    [query whereKey:@"Password" equalTo:password];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
        {
            for (PFObject *object in objects)
            {
                // retreive data
                NSString * firstName = [object objectForKey:@"UserFirstName"];
                NSString * lastname = [object objectForKey:@"UserLastName"];
                NSString * emailID = [object objectForKey:@"EmailID"];
                NSString * address = [object objectForKey:@"Address"];
                NSString * aptNo = [object objectForKey:@"AptNo"];
                NSString * city = [object objectForKey:@"City"];
                NSString * state = [object objectForKey:@"State"];
                NSString * zipcode = [object objectForKey:@"Zipcode"];
                NSString * phone = [object objectForKey:@"Phone"];


                //put it in array
                UserData * userData = [[UserData alloc]init];
                userData.fname = firstName;
                userData.lname = lastname;
                userData.emailID = emailID;
                userData.address = address;
                userData.aptNo = aptNo;
                userData.city = city;
                userData.state = state;
                userData.zipcode =zipcode;
                userData.phone = phone;

                [self.array_userData addObject:userData];
            }
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved: %@", objects);
        }
        else
        {
            NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorString);
        }
    }];
```

Comment: What is the error? Print `objects` to see exactly what you are getting back, at least ass the first part of it to the question. What is `UserData`? Is `array_userData` a property and is it created, not just declared?

Comment: I do not receive any error, it just does not show anything in "NSLog". UserData is NSObject, I am about to send these data to another ViewController. @zaph

Comment: If you do need see anything, likely the block is not executed. Did you check that setting a breakpoint inside the block?

Comment: `UserData` is **not** `NSObject`, it is probably a subclass of `NSObject` but that does not describe what `UserData` is.

Comment: This is what the debugger breakpoints, single step, variable display is for: to track down bad code by examining execution and variables. Debugging is a big part of developing code, very few developers can write code without errors that need to be debugged, certainly not me. If neither of the`NSLog()s` executed then `retrieveDataFromParse` was probably not called.

Comment: I don't see an initialization of self.array_userData.  Just before the loop, add a line, `self.array_userData = [NSMutableArray array];`.  After the loop, `NSLog(@"%@", self.array_userData);`

Answer (score 0):

This is invalid:

```
PFQuery * query =[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
```

And should be:

```
PFQuery * query = [PFUser query];
```

Though I shouldn't work anyway as the password shouldn't be stored in plain text...